# How to add an angularui accordion-group dynamically

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, jquery-ui-accordion

In an angularjs service, I am adding the HTML for an accordion-group to the DOM of an accordion element.  What results is the display of the accordion-group as if it were a panel - no title bar, no collapse behavior.

I'm sure it is because the accordion gets initialized before the content is added.  The jQueryUI accordion has a refresh method for such occasions, but not sure how to get the angualrui accordion to recognize the new accordion group.

Comment: Can you please share a plunker of your work  here ??

Comment: please let us know if you found the solution and do accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope the following steps help :

1. get the reference of the element where you want to add the accordion

   HTML : `<div id = "myAccordion"> </div>`

   Controller : `var parent = angular.element("#myAccordion");`
2. Compile your accordion template and attach it to the parent

   Controller:  `var accordion = $compile("<div accordion> </div>")($scope);
                   parent.append(accordion);`

but this is a work around you should ideally have a directive to do DOM manipulation , perhaps you are coding with jquery in mind.